Trivial .idl file generating MIDL2003 Error
Here is a trivial .idl file:
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass Dummy : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window
    {
        Dummy();
    };
    [
        uuid(079fb898-e9a5-48b6-a3b9-af6a54c7488a),
            version(1.0)
    ]
    library MyLib
    {
        importlib("stdole32.tlb");
        importlib("stdole2.tlb");
        typedef enum OP {
            NONE,
            LT,
            GT,
            EQ,
            ABLT,
            ABGT,
            ABEQ
        } OP;
    };

}

When I try to compile just this file with VS2022 17.10.4, I get 2 MIDL2003 errors:
[msg]redefinition [context]: _FLAGGED_WORD_BLOB   wtypesbase.idl line 468
[msg]redefinition [context]: IUnknown             unknwnbase.idl line 42

Commenting out both of the imports eliminates the error, although commenting out either one does not. They are not necessary for this repro, but I need them in my real app.  Suggestions?

First listed symptom

@HansPassant Thanks for replying.  I've expanded my trivial .idl file to show why the two imports can't be eliminated.  If they are commented out, the importlib statements within the namespace import them, and it is illegal to import them inside a namespace.
